# Hover event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The on hover event never gets called. anyone know why?

```
function prepare(){
    ... AJAX CALL...
    var embed = '<video preload="auto" class="videos_class" "><source src="'+webmUrl+'" type="video/webm"></video>';

    $( "<h1> "+title+" </h1>"+embed  ).appendTo( "#videos_div" );
}
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    prepare();

    $("video").hover(function(){
        this.play();
    },function(){
        this.pause()
  });
});
```

Comment: Probably because of `.. AJAX CALL...`. You may try to bind the event handler before the elements exist.

Comment: Not sure, but you really need to avoid concatenating data directly into HTML like you are now.  Your URL and title should be encoded.  At best, you're creating invalid HTML, and at worst you are opening yourself up to execution of arbitrary code.

Comment: In a land far far away, there is a strange concept called *event delegation*. I'd suggest you to go on a terrifying quest and explore that mystical land.

Comment: I believe Felix is correct. As a result of the ajax call executing asynchronously the video never has a source to be able to play. If you placed a console.log inside of the hover callbacks, you would more than likely notice the log being executed (but play will not work as there is no video loaded).

Answer (score 0):

Try document.on. It should work with elements added after the DOM is ready. Further investigation revealed that document.on and hover do not mix, but separate mouseover/mouseout handlers should do the trick:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'video', function(){
    $(this).play();
});

$(document).on('mouseout', 'video', function(){
    $(this).pause();
});
```

[jquery .on() docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Close but that's not it.

Comment: Right. 'hover' doesn't work with document.on. Would need separate mouseover, mouseout handlers instead.